# need to add current location to firestore with nullsaftey in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, location, geopoints

I use the packages below:

```yaml
google_maps_flutter: 
cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
location: ^4.2.0
```

I have this code:

```dart
storUserLocation()async{
       Location location = new Location();
    
    location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
      
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('parking_location').add({
      
        'location' : GeoPoint(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude)
        
      });
```

And it returns [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBlex.png).

Comment: What does the error say, in the underlined text? Your debug console is showing a different unrelated error. Also always paste code, not pictures of your code/error reports.

Comment: You can however add a `!` or do null check, to tell flutter that ot won't be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LocationData.longitude` and `LocationData.latitude` returns `double?` which means the return values could be null.

You can get rid of the errors by adding a check to ensure that the values are not null before you use them. Checkout below:

```dart
location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
 
  if (currentLocation.latitude != null && currentLocation.longitude != null) {     
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('parking_location').add({
        'location' : GeoPoint(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude)
      }); 
  }
}
```

Read more on null safety [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety).